# How do you calculate F-value for three groups, given only the mean and standard deviation in Python

Tags: anova, statsmodels

I am learning about power analysis for different scenarios in Python, e.g. for three groups (assuming equal sample in each group). I've seen videos demo for SPSS and other softwares, where you simply put in mean and stdev for each group and the total # of groups and then it gives you an output of effect size. So I assume that's achievable in Python too.

I've done something similar for two groups through t-test, being 1) determine effect size through Cohen's d formula 2) plug into TTestIndPower function in Python to get sample size.

However, let's say I have three groups, and I expected group 1: mean - 50, stdev - 2; group 2: mean - 61, stdev - 4; group 3: mean - 49, stdev - 3.0. I want to calculate how many sample is needed for each group. I know I can use FTestAnovaPower once I get the effect size, but I just don't know how to get that from just the mean and stdev.

Thank you!

Comment: examples for standard, Welch and mean-Brown-Forsythe anova are here https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.stats.oneway.effectsize_oneway.html  but I don't remember the references